# How To change Text to Speech Mac Sierra

Tags: macos, speech, voiceover, macos-sierra, dictation

There was a setting OSX Yosemite where you could change your dication voice and speed. Does anyone know how to find those settings on macs latest macOS Sierra?

I have looked under keyboard where there are dictation settings but that seems to be you speaking to your computer and it typing it out.

Also looked at accessibility and Voice over settings but not what I am looking for.

The Default voice was Alex and there is a speak back speed that you can change.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Accessibility -> Speech contains the settings you mention.

Comment: You are the winner I have been looking all over for this  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[Accessibitity > Speech](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gu9g.png)

Here you can set speed and choose the voise just like in Yosemite